# Create a custom library module in SuitScript 2.0?

Tags: javascript, module, amd, netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to create a custom profiler library to load into my SuiteScript 2.0 scripts. Its path is /SuiteScripts/profiler.js and my Suitelet is in /SuiteScripts/suitelet.js

Here how I am trying to load it into my suitelet:

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/log', 'N/file', './profiler'],
  function(serverWidget, log, file, profiler) {
    function onRequest(context) {

      log.debug('profiler', profiler) // --> logs undefined
```

I've tried two approaches in profiler.js:

Approach #1:

```
function Profiler() {
  var profileInstance = {};
  // add methods to profileInstance
  return profileInstance
}
```

Approach #2:

```
require([],
 function() {
   function profiler() {
     var profilerInstance = {};
     // add methods to profilerInstance
     return profilerInstance;
   }
return {
  profiler: profiler
 };
});
```

In Approach #2 I also added a comment indicating the SuiteScript version and require.config:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 */
require.config({
 shim: {
  'profiler': {
    exports: 'profiler'
  }
},
 paths: {
  profiler: '/SuiteScripts/Buy Request/profiler.js'
 }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Have you tried inserting some logging mechanism to test if it's actually loading properly? That is, within the profiler itself...

Comment: log.debug('typeof profiler', typeof profiler) // --> also logs undefined.

I need to get a function, or an object, loaded in as a starting point. I must not be wiring things up correctly.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `define` instead of `require` to build your custom modules. Just change your Approach #2 to call `define` instead of `require`, and you should be good to go.

I am not sure whether `require.config` works with SuiteScript or not. You shouldn't need it specifically for this use case.

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote your answer, but I'm too much of a noob!